# Jasmin IDE plugin or editor

Tags: java, jasmin

I have a `.class` file I need to edit and [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) would be a viable way to do it. I found the [Jasclipse](http://jasclipse.sourceforge.net/) plugin, but that's apparently too old and I cannot install it into newer Eclipse IDE.

Do you know of good way to edit `.class` files with Jasmin code? Or know of a plugin for Netbeans or Eclipse or IntelliJ that does the same thing?

Thanks in advance for insight.

Answer (score 1):

http://jasclipse.sf.net/update

EDIT:
This is the most recent thing I know of... One hopes someone else knows a bit more. I'm guessing you want to generate a .class file in "jvm assembly", not edit one, as there are a few more viable ways to transform an existing class file, most notably [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) which is pretty much the industry standard at this point.

If what you *actually* need is to transform  (edit) an existing .class file, ASM provides a nice java DSL to do the transformation directly in java so your IDE is all you need.

Sorry that the Initial answer was a bit brief.  I like futzing with byte-code and I'm sad the jasclipse plugin died.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This plugin has not been updated since 2007 and no the artifact is no longer available, it seems... tried installing it but a file could not be found.

Comment: Sorry for the bervity, updated the answer to be a bit more clear.